# JavaScript anti bot measures

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I have an firefox addon that inserts javascript into web pages.
Monitors clicks, and based on those clicks it provides a service to the user that works off my server.

The issue is that I dont want it to be used by bots or automation since it costs money every time I provide this service.
What are some anti-bot measures in firefox or javascript I can do to avoid this abuse?

Comment: JavaScript can be easily beaten since it's executed on the client side, bots can even ignore the code.

Answer (score 3):

As user can edit his code, it would not be reliable - use server-side protection like limit-per-api, per-ip, per-username key and so on...

Answer (score 1):

you cant do anything about this clientside except maybe implement a captcha. However serverside you could impose a per IP limit on the number of queries a user requests. Also you could implement a blacklist like [Barracuda RBL](http://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl) that lists IP addresses of bot infested computers.